# Randomize order of html survey MTURK

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

I'm putting up a survey involving radio buttons, free responses, and all the usual HTML form elements on Amazon MTURK and I would like to randomize the order of the questions. What's the easiest way to approach this? I'm presuming that I'll go at it with javascript unless there clearly a better way.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Yes, this is possible with javascript. But, that's not always the best idea in a HIT because workers can see the HIT in "preview" mode and once they accept the HIT, everything will be re-randomized due to a page load. Workers also can leave and return to HITs at any time. You may want to explore an off-site survey tool instead that allows server-side randomization.

Comment: that's super useful to know. thanks.